# Matrix Tree Theorem Proof Question

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, determinant

I was going through the following proof for the [Matrix Tree Theorem](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~reiner/Classes/Matrices.pdf) (see a screenshot of part of the proof below).

[image]

> $\textbf{Question:}$ I am confused about the last red rectangle in the proof. To me, property $4$ states the $v^{th}$ row and column should be deleted from $L(G-\{e\})_0$ to yield $L(G-\{e\})_e$. What does vertex $u$ have to do with anything at all? I feel like I am missing something..

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are deleting rows and columns corresponding to vertices $u$ and $v$ in the matrix $L(G-\{e\})$, which is basically the same then deleting $v$ in $L(G-\{e\})_0$ (up to 1 offset).